How to get NETTypeInfo as an Association to store in a variable and query it?
Needs["NETLink`"];

data=NETTypeInfo["System.GC"]

This prints the output using CellPrint so I can't store it in a variable. I tried using:
Block[{CellPrint=Inactive[CellPrint]},
    data=NETTypeInfo["System.GC"]
]

But now this is in weird box form. I just want it as a nested association so I can easily query it.
Even just a list of rows will be enough. How to I convert all the boxes to their expression? StyleBox,RowBox,GridBox etc.

If you want to get a plaintext without formatting, use the following:
Block[{$FrontEnd, TableForm = Identity}, NETTypeInfo["System.GC"]]

To get the raw data, you need to block all "formatting" functions used inside NETTypeInfo:
Block[{NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeAssemblyMemberRows = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeCtorRow = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeEventRow = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeFieldRow = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeHeading = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeMethodRow = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeParams = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makePropRow = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`makeTypeRows = # &, 
  NETLink`Reflection`Private`formatOutput = # &},
  AssociationThread[{"Types", "Constructors", "Fields", "Properties", 
    "Methods", "Events"} -> NETLink`NETTypeInfo["System.GC"]]
 ]


Thank you! Is there a way to still get the formatting of the text Bold etc in the first method: Block[{$FrontEnd, TableForm = Identity}, NETTypeInfo["System.GC"]]. I want the List of Strings but if String can be formatted in the way they were when they were getting Print?
